# How to find difference in time from current date and an query datetime in python?

Tags: python, datetime, date, range, timedelta

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| area_id | date_1              | date_2              |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    NULL | 2012-06-28 10:09:18 | 2012-06-28 10:15:48 |
|      18 | 2012-06-28 10:15:48 | 2012-06-28 10:20:26 |
|      21 | 2012-06-28 10:20:26 | 2012-06-28 10:32:51 |
|       3 | 2012-06-28 10:32:51 | 2012-06-28 10:50:27 |
|      21 | 2012-06-28 10:50:27 | 2012-06-28 11:36:36 |
|      18 | 2012-06-28 11:36:36 | 2012-06-28 11:39:26 |
|      21 | 2012-06-28 11:39:26 | 2012-06-28 11:40:33 |
|       3 | 2012-06-28 11:40:33 | 2012-06-28 11:48:03 |
|       7 | 2012-06-28 11:48:03 | NULL                |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Please helpme with range for a area_id beetwen date1 and date_2

```
datetime.now() - date_2
```

Thanks

Comment: What you wrote is pretty much what I would do. If you subtract a `datetime` from another `datetime`, you get a `timedelta` object telling you the exact difference.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

When subtracting two datetime objects, the result is a timedelta object.

```
from datetime import timedelta
difference = datetime.now() - date_2
```

The timedelta object contains the difference in time, and you can retrieve the value by using

```
difference.days
# or
difference.seconds
```

Whichever you need.